# For what reasons should I make classes private?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I review my code, and implement what I've learned, there's one thing that's bothering me. Why does it matter if these methods, or methods in general are private?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :require_login

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def require_login
    if session.include? :user_id
      user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You must be signed in to do that!"
    end
  end

  helper_method :current_user

end
```

Some methods refer to abstracting away functionality. I don't see a need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Rails guide

> Only public methods are callable as actions. It is a best practice to lower the visibility of methods (with `private` or `protected`) which are not intended to be actions, like auxiliary methods or filters.

The general practice to make all helper methods supporting actions as private methods. This helps to demarcate actions from helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

When developing an API (in the traditional sense: a description of how to use your program, in this cases Classes and Methods), `private` marks that it is a method that is not necessary to know about (and/or even not favorable to call from "outside") when you want to interact with that class, or an instance of it.

Regarding "does it matter?": In Ruby from a technical perspective: not really. If you want, you can call private methods on other objects (with "tricks", but **not** with the usual invokation: `@myobject.themethod()`).

From a user perspective: a lot. You are communicating how you want your stuff to be used.

From a developer perspective: also a log, if you consider the users (see point before). If you actively think about your API (modules, classes, methods) and consciously use `private` you might end up with better designed "interfaces" (API).

Note that in other programming languages (e.g. Java) `public`, `protected` and `private` might also strongly declare how e.g. subclasses can access certain internals of your classes and interfaces (here the word "Interface" denotes a language feature). So if you ever use another language, be sure to check out how `private` is meant there.

I didnt find official documentation on private, but e.g. this rubyguide: https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/method-visibility/ .